# Profile Image does not appear when I run the app.

Tags: swift3

Theres no error in my code but ImagevIew image doesn't show

let imageCache = NSCache()

extension UIImageView {

```
func loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: String) {
    //self.image = nil
    if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
        self.image = cachedImage
        return
    }

    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            if let currImage = UIImage(data: data!) {
                imageCache.setObject(currImage, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
                self.image = currImage
            }
        })
    }).resume()
}
```

}

Comment: Did your image downloaded without any error and didn't displayed in imageView only ?

Comment: it did download without an error but it just doesn't appear on the imageView